# Entity Framework with MYSql, return no column in complex entity return type

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4, edmx

I'm using MySQL in combination with an edmx file. I'm facing a problem when adding a function to stored procedure.
When I select "complex type" and press the "get column information" button I receive the following message:
"The selected stored procedure returns no columns."

When I create the same procedure in SQL Server and then added the function to a new edmx file, its creating the complex type perfectly.

Thanks,

Nauman

Comment: sometimes two different types of sql servers have minor differences. maybe the storage procedure is the problem itself. have you tried running this sp in mysql and viewed the results?

Comment: yeah i tried MySql giving result perfectly in mysql editor, but not giving in edmx

Comment: I have same issue with MySql.  SQL server imports works fine.